# How to pass a response of a api to junit request sampler in jmeter?

Tags: java, junit, jmeter

I have integrated selenium code with JMeter using JUnit request sampler.
I want to navigate to a URL which I will get from an API response. For this, I can pass a runtime value (URL) to the JUnit jar file.
To achieve this, I need to pass response of an API to the JUnit sampler.
How can we do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can extract the "interesting" value using any suitable [JMeter PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and store it into [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
2. The variable can be used in the [JUnit Request](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter) sampler like:

   ```
   String value = JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables().get("your_variable_name_here");
   ```

   You will need to link your project with [Apache JMeter Core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_core) in order to have access to [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) class

---

In the majority of cases it's easier to go for [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) in order to get Selenium integration

Answer (score 1):

you can add a "Regular Expression Extractor" to your API-Sampler to get the necessary string from the response. The extracted string can be used by `${ReferenceName}`.

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Best tifi

Comment: Actually, it solved my half problem. Upvoted for that.